# Panoramtech ads on Firefox (ShowIP extension)

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, malware

Since yesterday [Noscript](http://noscript.net/) - the extension for Firefox, blocks a request to "panoramtech.net".
After some researches, it seems that [Panoramtech](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-panoramtech-net-removal/) is a malware. 
How could my Linux system catch it? 
What should I do for safely and definitively remove it from my Kubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Did you add an extension?

Comment: After removing Firefox's extension [ShowIP][1] the malware request disappear...
[http://gavtaylor.co.uk/blog/malware-warning-showip-addon-for-firefox][2]

  [1]: https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/showip/
  [2]: http://gavtaylor.co.uk/blog/malware-warning-showip-addon-for-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by OP:

The [ShowIP extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/showip/) is the bad guy, and it is calling the malware page.

> A new version was pushed out yesterday, v2.5, and it injects a request into every page load to a site thats seems to be well known for malware. I highly recommend disabling it or rolling back to v2.4 if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

For me on Chrome, it was Dailymotion Video downloader with an ID of fjbeholgeggnndklobjgccindfdgbnld. It has since been removed from the store.

Comment: downvoter, please explain